# Cannot compile mongodb_ecto in phoenix elixir

Tags: mongodb, compilation, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to start an application using phoenix with mongodb.

When I try to run `mix phoenix.server`, I'm receiving this error message:

```
could not compile dependency :mongodb_ecto, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile mongodb_ecto", update it with "mix deps.update mongodb_ecto" or clean it with "mix deps.clean mongodb_ecto"
```

In my dependencies file, I have theese versions.

```
defp deps do
[{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.6"},
 {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
 {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0.2"},
 {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
 {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
 {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
 {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
 {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
 {:mongodb_ecto, "~> 0.1"},
 {:ecto, "~> 1.1.9"}
]
```

end

I made any downgrades to solve conflicts in versions. How can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `mix clean` then `mix deps.get` then `mix compile`

Comment: Same error:
http://pastebin.com/QJs9sR61

Comment: Based on that pastebin, it looks like the version of `mongodb` being used may be incorrect or not loaded or something. Did you do `mix clean --all`? What is the exact version of the `mongodb_ecto` and `mongodb` package that you are using? (Check your `mix.lock` file if you are not sure)

Comment: As a side note, you are using old versions of packages. This may be because the mongo adapter does not yet fully support ecto 2. However, there is [some work](https://github.com/michalmuskala/mongodb_ecto/pull/91) being done to remedy that. Hopefully, I will find time to fix the rest of the issues sooner than later. Though, the adapter is working quite well for at least myself and someone else that is running it in production.